# Append text at beginning of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

How to automatically add a text at beginning of edittext as soon as user start typing in it.For example I want to automatically append country code as soon as user start typing phone number.
I tried-

```
      mNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            mNumber.setText("+91"+editable.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

But this doesn't worked and my device hangs as soon as i type in the edittext.

Answer (score 9):

You're causing an infinite loop because you're calling `setText()` from `afterTextChanged()`, then `setText()` is calling `afterTextChanged()` and so on and so forth.

you can change your `afterTextChanged()` to the following,

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(!s.toString().startsWith("+91")){
        s.insert(0, "+91");
    }
}
```

This way you're not calling `setText()` all the time, also the check is there so that you're not adding "+91" each time the user types something in the EditText. One drawback to this method is that you can't delete the "+91" by backspace, once its been automatically inserted at the beginning of the input.

Comment: i also need to add-   `Selection.setSelection(mNumber.getText(), mNumber.getText().length());` otherwise i see multiple +91 ..please explain what does it do and why its necessary here?

Answer (score 4):

Your app hangs, because `mNumber.setText("...")` triggers your addTextChangedListener() again, and again, and again...

You can avoid that by checking if the prefix is already set and only prepending the prefix if it is not.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (!mNumber.getText().startsWith("+91")) {
        mNumber.setText("+91"+mNumber.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: i also need to add-   `Selection.setSelection(mNumber.getText(), mNumber.getText().length());` otherwise i see multiple +91..please explain what does it do and why its necessary here?

Answer (score 4):

Improvement over @wanpanman's answer

```
ET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int count;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                count=i2;
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!s.toString().startsWith("+91 ") && count!=0){
                    s.insert(0, "+91 ");
                }
            }
        });
```

The count variable makes sure that +91 isn't added twice while deleting the 1st instance of +91.

When count = 0, it indicates backspace.